# React-table data flow between outside and inside of hooks.visibleColumns.push invocation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I would like to create an array outside `useTable` invocation, manipulate the array, and based on the array state make checkbox checked or unchecked. After each click on a button, length of the array is increased by adding one element to the array. When length become greater than 3, the `input` should be checked.

The problem is that the array state is different inside and outside `checked` attribute of `input`. Outside it works as expected: the array length increases. Inside, the array length is equal to initial length of 0.

I have attached code with some logging. I think that the relevant part probably ends with the end of `useTable` invocation (then is some code which I took from `react-table` docs with button and mock data, columns added). What changes should I introduce to the code to make it work as I expect?

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table'

function Table({ columns, data }) {

  // neither stateArr nor simpleArr help reach what I would like to
  const [stateArr, setStateArr] = useState([]);
  let simpleArr = [...stateArr];

  const handleOnButtonClick = () => {
    console.log("Outside checked: simpleArr, stateArr");
    console.log(simpleArr);
    console.log(stateArr);
    setStateArr([...stateArr, 1]);
    // in this case unnecessary, since, as I understand, simpleArr is rendered and (re)assigned above
    // simpleArr = [...stateArr];
  };

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  },
  (hooks) => {
    hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => {
      return [
        {
          id: 'checkedInputs',
          Header: () => {
            return (<div>
              <input type="checkbox"
                   // working, not most elegant way to combine logging and computing boolean
                   checked={console.log("Inside checked: simpleArr, stateArr") || console.log(simpleArr)
                     || console.log(stateArr) || simpleArr.length > 3 || stateArr.length > 3} />
            </div>);
          },
          Cell: () => {
            return (<div>R</div>);
          },
        },
        ...columns,
        ];
    });
  }
  );

  return (
    <div>
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onClick={handleOnButtonClick}>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Animal Type',
        accessor: 'animalType',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Number of legs',
        accessor: 'numberOfLegs',
      },
    ],
    [],
  );

  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        animalType: 'dog',
        numberOfLegs: 4,
      },
      {
        animalType: 'snake',
        numberOfLegs: 0,
      },
    ],
    [],
  );

  return (
    <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I believe you are dealing with a stale closure where the `Header` component is created with an initial value that gets outdated.  I've got to look at the docs to see what props we can pass to `Header` to avoid this.

Comment: The accepted solution works fine, but incase if anyone is looking into other ways to solve such an issue, try using `refs` as the current value of the `ref` would be the actual current value even if the function using it was rendered before the latest change was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Stale Data

The `hooks.visibleColumns.push` function is called one time when the table is created.  It creates a `Header` render component that takes some props and returns a JSX element.  The function which *renders* the `Header` based on these props is called every time that the table updates.  The function which *creates* this `Header` component is called **once**.

In your example, you create a `Header` component which prints out some data based on the values of `simpleArr` and `stateArr` **at the time that it was created**, not at the time that it was called.

#### Table State

If we want our `Header` component to render with current data then we should get that data from props.  The `Header` is called with quite a lot of props but the one that we will use is `state` which is the state of the table.  We will set the `initialState` of the table to an object `{ stateArr: [] }`.  This gets merged with the standard table state `{ hiddenColumns: [] }`.

The table state is updated through a `useReducer` hook, so we update it by `disptach`ing an action.  We need a custom `stateReducer` to update the table state based on the contents of the `action`.

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { useTable } from "react-table";

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    dispatch,
    state
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: {
        stateArr: []
      },
      stateReducer: (newState, action, prevState) => {
        console.log(action, newState, newState.stateArr);
        switch (action.type) {
          case "incrementChecks":
            return {
              ...newState,
              stateArr: [...newState.stateArr, action.payload]
            };
          default:
            return newState;
        }
      }
    },
    (hooks) => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => {
        return [
          {
            id: "checkedInputs",
            Header: (props) => {
              console.log("header props", props); // so you can see all the data you get
              console.log("stateArr", props.state.stateArr);
              return (
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  readOnly
                  checked={props.state.stateArr.length > 3}
                />
              );
            },
            Cell: () => {
              return <div>R</div>;
            }
          },
          ...columns
        ];
      });
    }
  );

  const handleOnButtonClick = () => {
    // payload is the item which we are appending to the array
    dispatch({ type: "incrementChecks", payload: 1 });
  };

  console.log("stateArr", state.stateArr);

  return (
    <div>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOnButtonClick}>
        Append
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Animal Type",
        accessor: "animalType"
      },
      {
        Header: "Number of legs",
        accessor: "numberOfLegs"
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        animalType: "dog",
        numberOfLegs: 4
      },
      {
        animalType: "snake",
        numberOfLegs: 0
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return <Table columns={columns} data={data} />;
}

export default App;
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/storing-data-in-react-table-state-jwufc?file=/src/App.jsx)